# Why cannot I use the Vim VSCode extension over ssh or wsl?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot install the Vim VSCode extension on my headless machine through VSCode remote development nor in WSL. I think I used to be able to but I uninstalled it once and since then I haven't been able to install it again. I can only install and uninstall on my Windows computer but not remotely: when I click the button to install Windows extensions to server, the Vim VSCode extension is not part of the batch:

[image: screenshot]

[image: main screenshot]

Edit: actually the extension stopped working in Windows as well without obvious reason.

Here is a list of my extensions: maybe I introduced incompatibilities I am not aware of:

[image: extensions]
[image: extensions Contd]

I wonder how to get a JSON list of the extensions by the way :(

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the settings JSON file. There was some syntax error, possibly caused by the installation of some other extension.

Answer (score 5):

I might be wrong but I don't believe the normal `VSCodeVim` extension requires Vim itself to be installed as it just emulates it, so it shouldn't need installed in the remote environment as long as it is installed/enabled which it looks to be. Is it not working?

Comment: I think this answer is irrelevant. Sorry if I misformulated my question.